# Change the size of parent without affecting the size of it's child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have inherited a project, in which a game object is the child of another game object. The size of the parent is unnecessarily bigger than the child, and I want them to be the same size and fit and tight. However, when I try to resize the parent, the child also resizes and gets smaller. What should I do?

Comment: First off unless the parent has a collider it shouldn't matter, but otherwise you could un-parent the child resize the parent and then re-child it.

Comment: Make the child's parent null, rescale the parent and reassign child's parent.

Answer (score 2):

That is the intended behavior between parent and child `GameObject`s you can break the connection ether throu the Editor or by setting the child `GameObject`'s `transform.parent` to  `null`. For example:

```cs
gameObject.transform.parent = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

A child changing any size or position is not what the whole concept is used for i would recommend maybe find a way around this, if the child is following the parent then maybe a script that transforms its position the same as the parent.

```
child.position = parent.transform.position;
```

just as an example.